# window.location.reload doesn't work

Tags: javascript, window.location

I have a timer on my page for 10 min. and when time exceed page supposed to refresh itself and remove the session values.

It was working very well but suddenly it stopped working.. Timer gets stuck at 0:01.

It's look like when location.reload() executes then page get stuck. Explorer's status bar keep showing the loading icon.. over and over again.

**My code is below:**

```
<script>
                    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

                    function timer() {
                        count = count - 1;

                        // if time exceed then refresh the page.
                        if (count <= 0) {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var timerSpan = document.getElementById("timerCountdown");

                            if (count <= timerTurnToRed) {
                                //Make Red
                                timerSpan.className = "finalCountdown";
                            }

                            // Calculate remaining minutes & seconds
                            var remainingMinutes = Math.floor(count / 60)

                            // Check if it is negative
                            if (remainingMinutes < 0)
                                location.reload();

                            var remainingSecs = count - (remainingMinutes * 60);
                            if (remainingSecs < 10) {
                                remainingSecs = "0" + remainingSecs.toString();
                            }

                            timerSpan.innerHTML = remainingMinutes + ":" + remainingSecs;
                        }
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: Where is the code that sets "count"?  It might be 0 after reload.

Comment: You didn't provide the all code of your problem...

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the timer keeps reloading over and over. Like it does `location.reload()` then before its done reloading the new page and clearing the old page it hits `location.reload()` again, causing it to stop loading again and starting over... and over... and over. Try stopping the interval with some check, maybe change test to `if(count===0)`

Comment: You didn't provide the all code of your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Don't get where is the problem it works as expected. StackOverflow code evaluator will prevent reloading.

```js
var count = 15;
var timerTurnToRed = 10;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

                    function timer() {
                        count--;

                        // if time exceed then refresh the page.
                        if (count <= 0) {
                            location.reload();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var timerSpan = document.getElementById("timerCountdown");

                            if (count <= timerTurnToRed) {
                                //Make Red
                                timerSpan.className = "finalCountdown";
                            }
                            
                            var remainingMinutes = Math.floor(count / 60);

                            // Check if it is negative
                            if (remainingMinutes < 0)
                                location.reload();

                            var remainingSecs = count - (remainingMinutes * 60);
                            if (remainingSecs < 10) {
                                remainingSecs = "0" + remainingSecs.toString();
                            }

                            timerSpan.innerHTML = remainingMinutes + ":" + remainingSecs;
                        }
                    }
```

```css
.finalCountdown {color: red;}
```

```html
<div id="timerCountdown"></div>
```

Comment: That's why we're guessing the code to set `count` is the problem.